# Bucketing data in R is giving error

Tags: r

I am trying to bucket my data into various categories and facing an issue while doing the same. I couldnt understand on where its going wrong. Any help please.

```
new_df<-original_df
new_df$bucket_column<-cut(
                as.numeric(
                  new_df$value_for_bucket_column),
                breaks=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,14,21,28,60,90,180,365,Inf),
                labels = c("1 Day","1-2 Days","2-3 Days","3- Days",
                "4-5 Days","5-6 Days", "1 Week",
                "1-2 Weeks","2-3 Weeks","3-4 Weeks",
                "1-2 Months","2-3 Months","3-6 Months",
                "6-12 Months","More than a Year"))
```

When I try to do the bucketing, I am facing an error as below:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "bucket_column", value = integer(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 24783
```

Please let me know where I am doing it wrong. Thanks

Comment: You need to provide more information, but there's a chance your `cut(..)` returns a zero-length vector. Is `as.numeric(new_df$value_for_bucket_column)` indeed a valid 24783-length numeric vector?

Comment: If I remove the as.numeric function and instead provide only new_df$value_for_bucket_column, then it completes successfully. But when I try to convert the output column into a column using table(new_df$bucket_column), and then try to see the values, it says table of extent 0 >.

Comment: Can you show the output of `str(new_df$value_for_bucket_column)` or sample data that reproduce the problem?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.